# Align pinned nodes in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

I'm working with plots generated from `matlab2tikz` and I have several plot lines close to each other. Labeling them is proving difficult, but I believe a good looking solution could be to list the labels, and draw vertical lines to the appropriate plot.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 3.5]
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=0,ymax=5]
        \addplot[domain=0:3,solid]{(x-4)^2}    node[pos=0.8,pin=-180:{Plot 1}] {} ;
        \addplot[domain=0:3,solid]{(x-3.5)^2}  node[pos=0.8,pin=-180:{Plot 2}] {} ;
        \addplot[domain=0:3,solid]{(x-3)^2}    node[pos=0.8,pin=-180:{Plot 3}] {} ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Given I don't know where the `addplot` plots will show up (i.e around `x = 3` or `x = 300`), is there a way to align the labels/nodes with equal height spacing, and have the pins extend until they reach the plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing TikZ and `pgfplots` can become tricky. The `scope` apparently executes the given options directly.

But here you go. The following code doesn’t use the `pin`/`pos` combo. I hope that at least the output is something you wanted. (You actually can overwrite the `at` part of the `every name plot node` style with the `/.append style` handler.)

I’m open for suggestions.

There exist a few more keys in the `name plot` namespace:

The keys `relative` (`relative x`/`relative y`) turns on the `rel axis cs` which “uses the complete axis vectors as units. That means 'x = 0' denotes the point on the lower x axis range and 'x = 1' the point on the upper x axis range […].”

I recommend the `relative [x|y]` option for the placement of the nodes (as you have said, you don’t know whether *x* is around 3 or 300, which is probably also true for *y*, unless you specify `xmin` and so on).
You can mix absolute and relative coordinate. The last example uses absolute *y* values but relative *x* values.

The `backwards` key finds the intersection from the highest to the lowest *y* value.

The `number`th intersection will be used (default: `1`).

The `anchor` key can be used to correct the edge (if the `anchor` key of the node is neither `west` nor `center` nor `east` the line will not be perfectly horizontal. The `anchor` key can be used to fix this. The preceding `.` must be included.

---

A possible improvement could be that the `\namePlot` finds the nearest point/intersection on its own (with the option to look only to the left or the right).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifqrr@nameplot@relative@x
\newif\ifqrr@nameplot@relative@y
\newif\ifqrr@nameplot@backwards
\tikzset{
  every name plot node/.style={
    anchor=east,
    name=\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/name}
  },
  name plot/.code={\pgfkeys{/name plot/.cd,#1}}}
\pgfqkeys{/name plot}{
  at x/.initial=0,
  at y/.initial=0,
  at/.style args={#1,#2}{/name plot/at x={#1},/name plot/at y={#2}},
  path name/.initial=,
  name/.initial=,
  anchor/.initial=,
  number/.initial=1,
  relative x/.is if=qrr@nameplot@relative@x,
  relative y/.is if=qrr@nameplot@relative@y,
  relative/.style={
    /name plot/relative x=#1,
    /name plot/relative y=#1
  },
  relative/.default=true,
  backwards/.is if=qrr@nameplot@backwards
}
\newcommand*{\namePlot}[2][]{
  \scope[/name plot/.cd,#1]
    \ifqrr@nameplot@relative@y
      \path (rel axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/at y}) coordinate (qrr@name plot@a)
            (rel axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/at y}) coordinate (qrr@name plot@b);
    \else
      \path (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/at y}) coordinate (qrr@name plot@a)
            (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/at y}) coordinate (qrr@name plot@b);
    \fi
    \ifqrr@nameplot@backwards
      \path[name path=qrr@nameplot@horizontal line] (qrr@name plot@b) -- (qrr@name plot@a);
    \else
      \path[name path=qrr@nameplot@horizontal line] (qrr@name plot@a) -- (qrr@name plot@b);
    \fi
    \path[
      name intersections={%
        of=\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/path name} and qrr@nameplot@horizontal line,
        name=qrr@nameplot@intersections,
        sort by=qrr@nameplot@horizontal line}
    ];
    \node[
      at={(perpendicular cs: horizontal line through={(qrr@nameplot@intersections-\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/number})},
                            vertical line through={(\ifqrr@nameplot@relative@x rel \fi axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/at x},0)})},
      every name plot node/.try,
      alias=qrr@nameplot@node
    ] {#2} (qrr@nameplot@node\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/anchor}) edge[every name plot edge/.try] (qrr@nameplot@intersections-\pgfkeysvalueof{/name plot/number});
  \endscope
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{every name plot edge/.append style={help lines, shorten >=2pt, -latex}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale = 3.5,
  /name plot/at x=.7
  ]
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=0,ymax=5]
        \addplot[domain=0:3, solid, name path global=plot 1]{(x-4)^2}  ;
        \addplot[domain=0:3, solid, name path global=plot 2]{(x-3.5)^2};
        \addplot[domain=0:3, solid, name path global=plot 3]{(x-3)^2}  ;
        \namePlot[path name=plot 1, at y=2, name=p1] {Plot 1}
        \namePlot[path name=plot 2, at y=3, name=p2] {Plot 2}
        \namePlot[path name=plot 3, at y=4, name=p3] {Plot 3}
        \path [<->] (p1) edge (p2) (p2) edge (p3);% just for fun
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale = 3.5,
  name plot={
    at x=.15,
    relative x},
  every name plot edge/.append style={preaction={draw=white,ultra thick,-}},
  every name plot node/.append style={anchor=west}
  ]
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=10,ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5]
        \addplot[domain=-1:10, solid, smooth, name path global=sinus]{sin(x/pi*180)}  ;
        \tikzset{/name plot/path name=sinus}
        \namePlot[at y=-.99 ] {$y=-1$}
        \namePlot[at y=-.5, number=2, backwards] {$y=-0.5$}
        \namePlot[at y=0] {$y=0$}
        \namePlot[at y=0, number=2, /tikz/every name plot node/.append style={text opacity=0}] {$y=0$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Comment: The execution order in pgfplots is different than TikZ, paths are not added consecutively but collected. We had some head scratching with Jake on this one too http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57582/change-linestyle-within-a-plot-to-add-dashed-trendline

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the comment/pointer.

Comment: Well not much of help though :) Is it OK to edit your answer if I can think of something else tomorrow?

Comment: @percusse Well the `scope` tip in one of your comments helped. The contents of `\namePlot` had to be grouped anyway … But sure, go ahead, if you find a more appropriate/stable way.

Comment: Nice solution! But should I experience difficulties when using the `table` option for providing points to `\addplot`?

Comment: @Holene Where there’s a path, there’s a way. I don’t know how `only marks` is processed internally, but otherwise there shouldn’t be any problems.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You're right, there's a way. Got some weird errors, but they originated from the `\namePlot` being positioned too high for the plot. It works now, thanks!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Could you please document your code? I think these are interesting plots so I really would like to understand how you got it going. thx