# Change line style in pgfplots in the middle of a line

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following MWE graph:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
    (1000,1)
    (1100,1.3589)
    (1200,2.5248)
    (1300,4.0476)
    (1400,7.9426)
    (1500,13.032)
    (1600,18.165)
    (1700,20.775)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to make the line turn into a dashed line after the 1400 point. This is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57582/change-linestyle-within-a-plot-to-add-dashed-trendline) but I want to supply my own data. How can I change style in the middle of an addplot?

Comment: Can you add the coordinates in two sets and add the `[dashed]` option to the second set?

Comment: How would I keep the line the same style? In my actual graph I am using `cycle list name=black white`

Comment: It would be an easy task with more `\addplot`s. We could add map with just only two colors (`colormap`), we could use `scatter` plot type, but that wouldn't solve your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm probably not satisfying the question, but it's rather an easy task with more `\addplot` commands in use, we only need to split up the data and preserve one common point for two consecutive sets - it is `(1400,7.9426)` point in this example. This approach works with two (as in this example) or even more separations.

```
%! *latex mal-tikz-graph.tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
    (1000,1)
    (1100,1.3589)
    (1200,2.5248)
    (1300,4.0476)
    (1400,7.9426)
    };
\addplot[no marks, dashed, red, line width=2pt] coordinates {
    (1400,7.9426)
    (1500,13.032)
    (1600,18.165)
    (1700,20.775)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: This actually looks like it may work; I'll have to try it.