# Change line style in specified sections of the plot - pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to be able to change the line style within a certain section of the graph given a single `addplot` command. Is there any way possible to change the properties of the line style for specified sections of the x axis? I have only seen similar Q&A addressing [multiple addplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170980/change-line-style-in-pgfplots-in-the-middle-of-a-line?noredirect=1&lq=1) to fulfill the different line style and also a [nice example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57582/change-linestyle-within-a-plot-to-add-dashed-trendline?noredirect=1&lq=1) in which it seems the solution is by adding a `draw` with a different style to meet the expectations of the question.. Though, it seems that it also just adds a different plot at the end plot visualization..

My MWE is shown below with an "ugly" solution of just splitting the sections as multiple `addplot` commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}   
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                    group size = 1 by 1,
                    },
                clip=true,
                enlargelimits=true,
                height = 0.75\columnwidth,
                width = 1\columnwidth,
                axis x line = center,
                axis y line = center,
                xlabel={$x$},
                xmin=0,
                xmax=3,
                xtick={0,1,2,3}
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[ymin=0,
                                ymax=10,
                                ytick={0,2,...,10},
                                ylabel = {$y$}
                                ]
    
                    \addplot[color=blue, domain = 0:1, samples=50                   
                            ] {x^2};
                    \addplot[color=blue, dashed, domain = 1:2, samples=50                   
                            ] {x^2};
                    \addplot[color=blue, domain = 2:3, samples=50                   
                            ] {x^2};
                            
            \end{groupplot}    
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't look like conditional styling or similar is implemented. But looks like you can try softclipping, see Ch. "5.5 Decoration: Soft Clipping" in the PGFPLOTSmanual. However, code won't become shorter ... or easier to understand ...

Comment: You could maybe use a custom dash pattern, but it would require a lot of calculation. I would actually stick to your version. It is at least clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `soft clip` provided by the `fillbetween` library (as suggested by MS-SPO in the comments) and create your custom style inspired by the example on page 104 of the [current PGFPlots manual (version 1.18.1)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{
    dashed between/.style args={#1:#2}{
        draw=none,
        postaction={
            draw,
            decorate,
            decoration={
                soft clip,
                soft clip path={
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle
                    (#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
                },
            }
        },
        postaction={
            draw,
            dashed,
            decorate,
            decoration={
                soft clip,
                soft clip path={
                    (#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle
                    (#2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
                },
            }
        },
        postaction={
            draw,
            decorate,
            decoration={
                soft clip,
                soft clip path={
                    (#2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
                },
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 1,
        },
        clip=true,
        enlargelimits=true,
        height=0.75\columnwidth,
        width=1\columnwidth,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xlabel={$x$},
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        xtick={0,1,2,3}
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        ytick={0,2,...,10},
        ylabel={$y$}
    ]

        \addplot[color=blue, domain={0:3}, dashed between={1:2}] {x^2};

        \addplot[color=red, domain={0:3}, dashed between={0.5:2.5}] {4};

    \end{groupplot}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: @MS-SPO It actually makes use of your suggestion to use `soft clip`. So, it is basically your idea ...

Comment: Maybe, but I would have failed implementing it.

Comment: great thanks Jasper!