# How to plot a dashed line for some data predictions followed from a solid line from historical data

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-styles, plot

### **Problem**

I have a set of data from a .dat file, which every value could be "historical" or "prediction".

```
year    emision   data_type
2008    9.24309   hist
2010    8.50724   hist
2012    8.06490   hist
2014    7.84779   hist
2016    7.22237   pred
2018    6.71319   pred
2020    6.26255   pred
```

I need to plot a solid a line with those data which are historical, and a dashed line with those which are predictions, in the same plot. Below is an example plot of what I want.

I have check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57582/change-linestyle-within-a-plot-to-add-dashed-trendline) but I didn't understand how to apply this, with data from a file.

[image: Plot example]

---

### What I have:

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\pgfplotstableread{data/example_data.dat}\datatable

\pgfplotstableread{
year    emision data_type
2008    9.24309 hist
2010    8.50724 hist
2012    8.06490 hist
2014    7.84779 hist
2016    7.22237 pred
2018    6.71319 pred
2020    6.26255 pred
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north}}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=\axisdefaultheight,
            legend columns=4,
            grid=major,
            cycle list name=exotic,             
            ]
    \addplot table[y=emision] from \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to tex.se! using two `\addplot`, one for domain of data, one for domain of predicted data? to show you how, you need to provide `example_data.dat`, without it your mwe (minimal working example) is not compilable.

Comment: I have edited, now must be compilable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a rude solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\pgfplotstableread{data/example_data.dat}\datatable

\pgfplotstableread{
year    emission data_type
2008    9.24309  hist
2010    8.50724  hist
2012    8.06490  hist
2014    7.84779  hist
2016    7.22237  pred
2018    6.71319  pred
2020    6.26255  pred
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(0.5,-0.1)},
        anchor=north}}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=\axisdefaultheight,
            legend columns=4,
            grid=major,
            cycle list name=exotic,
            ]
    \addplot            table[y=emission, x=year, restrict x to domain=2008:2014] from \datatable;
    \addplot +[dashed]  table[y=emission, x=year, restrict x to domain=2014:2020] from \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, I should've resolve the problem of the color, ideally have to be the same, but anyway this answer give me one good approach.

Comment: I've resolved using \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-1} after addplot. Thanks again!

Comment: @ArielNuñez, I'm, glad to hear this. Since this was not question, I assumed, that you select such appearing of function with purpose :-)