# Varying thickness hrule

Tags: sectioning, rules, line

I saw this format in a book and was wondering how to create the varying thickness horizontal rules above the section headers. I am assuming an MWE isn't necessary here. I got some idea [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36733/reuse-part-of-a-path/36781#36781) but I think there's probably something more simple than TikZ for this.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That doesn't look like a varying width rule, just two rules:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}

\nointerlineskip
\noindent\rule{3cm}{5pt}
\end{document}
```

For example using the section format mentioned in comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule}]

\renewcommand\titlerule{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}%
\par
\nointerlineskip
\noindent\rule{3cm}{5pt}\par}}
\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried using what I found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/how-can-i-make-a-bold-horizontal-rule-under-each-section-title to make it do this for each section but I get an error. I tried

`\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\sffamily\slshape}{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}\nointerlineskip\noindent\rule{3cm}{5pt}\thesection}{1em}{}`

Comment: @FahimAbdullah I updated the answer