# tikz Multi-segment Line of Varying Thickness

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a multi-segment line with TikZ as below:

```
\begin{figure*}
\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0.25,0) --(0.75,1.2) -- (1.25,1.5) -- (1.75,0.7) -- (2.25,1.1) -- (2.75,0.5) -- (3.25,1.5) -- (4.25,1.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
```

I'd like a few of the segments of the line to be thick, and the rest to be thin. Or, put another way, I'd like the line to be thick from `(0.25,0)` up until `(1.75,0.7)`.

If I just do `\draw[thick] ...` the whole line becomes thick, which is not what I want.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't possible without splitting the path into segments, or doing something a little fancy.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43309/86 for one way to do this.  Is that close to what you want?

Comment: That looks pretty good, but I couldn't get it working, and it's unclear if you can mix `to[]` blocks with `--` connections.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, I've commented on the answer you linked to above - the code there doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: There was a spurious blank line.  I've removed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is somewhere on the site but about dashed line and solid line. I can't  find this answer but I will delete my answer if someone gives the good link

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\tikzset{%
xultra thick/.style={to path={%
\pgfextra{%
 \draw[line cap=round, line join=round,ultra thick]
      (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);} (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
xthin/.style={to path={%
\pgfextra{%
 \draw[line cap=round, line join=round,thin] 
       (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget);} (\tikztotarget)  \tikztonodes}}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0.25,0) -- (0.75,1.2) -- (1.25,1.5) 
  to[xultra thick]  (1.75,0.7) -- (2.25,1.1) -- (2.75,0.5)
                 -- (3.25,1.5) to[xthin] (4.25,1.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33712/is-there-a-tikz-dashed-line-decorator-or-some-other-way-to-make-part-of-a-path-d) is the original question and [this is your nice elaboration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36733/reuse-part-of-a-path/36781#36781).

Comment: No there is another answer with xdashed and xsolid styles.

Answer (score 1):

In a very basic way you can break the segment into two subsegments:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0.25,0) --(0.75,1.2) -- (1.25,1.5) -- (1.75,0.7); 
\draw[->] (1.75,0.7) -- (2.25,1.1) -- (2.75,0.5) -- (3.25,1.5) -- (4.25,1.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Another solution that allows you to decide the thickness of the line is:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[line width=1pt] (0.25,0) --(0.75,1.2) -- (1.25,1.5) -- (1.75,0.7); 
 \draw[->,line width=0.5pt](1.75,0.7) -- (2.25,1.1) -- (2.75,0.5) -- (3.25,1.5) -- (4.25,1.8);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```