# tikz Join line segments of different thickness with miter

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, svg

Reading ["tikz Multi-segment Line of Varying Thickness"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51546/tikz-multi-segment-line-of-varying-thickness) provides a good explanation to join segments, but it seems that the rounded corner transition is the only way to do this nicely?

I would like to join segments of different thickness with a nice sharp miter, getting similar results in the case of these two:

Lines of the same thickness have a nice miter:

```
\draw [very thick] (0.45,-0.2) to (0.45,0.17) to (0.75,-0.17) to (0.75,0.2);
```

But if I try to join a thick line to a thin line, there is an artifact:

```
\draw [very thick] (1.3,0.2) to (1,0) to (1.3,-0.2);
\draw (1,0) to (1.3,-0.2) to (1.3,0.2) to (1,0);
```

[image: nice miter same thickness, but nasty joints between two]

The resulting mitre would appear thus (except not edited by hand):

[image: desired mitre]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a work around using `\clip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (1.3,0.2) -- (1,0) -- (1.3,-0.2) -- (1.3,0.2) -- cycle;
  \draw [line width=2pt] (1.3,0.2) to (1,0) to (1.3,-0.2);
  \draw (1.3,-0.2) to (1.3,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that a line width of `2pt` will give a resultant line width of `1pt` as the other part is clipped off. So you have to adjust properly.

If this forms a part of bigger diagram, the `\clip`ping part may be enclosed in a `scope` so as to limit the clipping:

```
\begin{scope}
   \clip (1.3,0.2) -- (1,0) -- (1.3,-0.2) -- (1.3,0.2) -- cycle;
   \draw [line width=2pt] (1.3,0.2) to (1,0) to (1.3,-0.2);
   \draw (1.3,-0.2) to (1.3,0.2);
\end{scope}
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution.

Comment: This is much simpler than any workaround I would have come up with (in a reasonable time frame). Too bad this result has to be rent by brute force.

Comment: It might be good to mention the clip command affects any code coming after as well. Wrapping the snippet in `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}` seems to keep things contained.

Comment: @repurposer: It is evident. I wasn't aware of the entire picture you are trying to draw. I have added the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you use `line cap=round` along with `line join=round`, and a slight `xshift` to connect these.  Here is a before and after comparison:

[image]

### References:

- [In TikZ when is "line join=miter" the preferrable over "line join=round"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21063/in-tikz-when-is-line-join-miter-the-preferrable-over-line-join-round)

### Notes:

- Also in the original version, you were *not* just drawing a thin line, you were actually drawing over the thick lines as can be seen by using the color `red` option to the `very thick` line:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [very thick] (1.3,0.2) to (1,0) to (1.3,-0.2);
\draw (1,0) to (1.3,-0.2) to (1.3,0.2) to (1,0);  

\begin{scope}[xshift=0.5cm, draw=blue]
\draw [line cap=round, line join=round, very thick] (1.3,0.2) -- (1,0) -- (1.3,-0.2);
\draw [line cap=round, shift={(0.1ex,0)}] (1.3,-0.2) to (1.3,0.2);  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, I was drawing over the very thick lines, i guess that could be removed from the example. Except the attempt was, to force the miter joiner. In this case, my preferred result would be to have sharp corners. Rounded joints do not suit the stylistic requirements of the graphic.

Comment: @repurposer: If you don't want to use round corners, how do you suggest that a `very thick` line and a `thin` have a corner? The only option I can think of is to have a curved line (with minimal curvature) as the `thin` line so that it can go out and come in at an angle.  Would that be an option?

Comment: see updated post -- the idea would be to extrapolate the edges of the line segments such that they intersect (as is done with same-sized segments), and preventing the 'thickness' of the line to cause it to bulge out beyond the outer edge of the other

Comment: @repurposer: Oh, I see. I can only think of a manual way to do that, which would not be useful if you need to do this often.  Sorry, I was not able to be of more help.  Oppsss, did not realize you were a new user...

Comment: And thanks, @Peter Grill. I think, in this case a manual solution would be ok because I will only use it once or twice tonight -- but, useful things are useful.

Answer (score 4):

Rather more of this had to be done by eye than I would have liked, but nevertheless this is possible with the arrow heads defined at [TikZ: changing colour of a path half way along](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10980/86) (see my third (!) answer there (chronologically) and Qrrbrbirlbel's).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157254/86}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{
  /tikz/sharp arrow angle/.code={%
    \pgfsetarrowoptions{sharp left}{#1}
    \pgfsetarrowoptions{sharp right}{#1}
  },
  /tikz/sharp left arrow angle/.code={%
    \pgfsetarrowoptions{sharp left}{#1}
  },
  /tikz/sharp right arrow angle/.code={%
    \pgfsetarrowoptions{sharp right}{#1}
  }
}

\tikzset{sharp arrow angle=30}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{sharp left}{sharp left}{%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{.5*\pgflinewidth * tan(\pgfgetarrowoptions{sharp left})}
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{\pgf@xa}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{\pgf@xa}
}{%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\pgflinewidth * tan(\pgfgetarrowoptions{sharp left})}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.1\pgflinewidth}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.1\pgflinewidth}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}
\pgfarrowsdeclare{sharp right}{sharp right}{%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{.5*\pgflinewidth * tan(\pgfgetarrowoptions{sharp right})}
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{\pgf@xa}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{\pgf@xa}
}{%
  \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\pgflinewidth * tan(\pgfgetarrowoptions{sharp right})}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.1\pgflinewidth}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.1\pgflinewidth}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}
  \pgfusepathqfill
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=20]
\pgfmathsetmacro\ang{90 - atan2(.3,.2)}
\draw [line width=2cm,sharp arrow angle=\ang,sharp left-sharp right] (1.3,0.2) to (1,0) to (1.3,-0.2);
\draw [blue,line width=1cm,sharp arrow angle=\ang,sharp left-sharp right] (1.3,-0.2603) to (1.3,0.2603);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mitred corners via arrows]