# Smoothing out angles made up of different line widths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm reproducing someone else's example where an angle is created with two lines of differing thickness. My problem is smoothing out the intersection of these two lines. Here is my current outcome:

[image]

My desired outcome would be one where the `very thick` line never goes below the horizontal line.

And my current MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=bevel] % line join=round, miter also do not work
    \draw[line cap=round] (0,0) node[left] {$0$} -- (1,0) node[right] {$t$};
    \draw[very thick,->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've tried the `clip` work around from [tikz Join line segments of different thickness with miter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157254/tikz-join-line-segments-of-different-thickness-with-miter), but I can't get this to work. I've also tried various `line join` options as found in [How to fix TikZ corners in 3D](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21054/how-to-fix-tikz-corners-in-3d?noredirect=1&lq=1), but again to no avail.

Is my only option an (ugly) approach with `shorten <` like `\draw[very thick,->,shorten <=0.4] (0,0) -- (1,1);`?

I will ultimately be using LuaLaTeX, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\clip` more or less works for me

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=bevel] % line join=round, miter also do not work
    \draw[line cap=round] (0,0) node[left] {$0$} -- (1,0) node[right] {$t$};
    \clip (-0.2,-0.2pt) rectangle (1.1,1.1);
    \draw[very thick,->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apart from some confusion on my end regarding `clip`, I was expecting an automatic approach, but this works. I assume you chose `-0.2pt` as the y coordinate due to the thickness of the horizontal line?

Comment: @Richard Yes is the half of the thickness of the horizontal line.